# removeEventListener error happen when building tic tac toe

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, dom-events

I am trying to make the tic-tac-toe game. I have tried to use `removeEventListener` to remove the click after the circle or X are appear in the square so the image will not appear twice. However `removeEventListener` cause the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object.

Is there any method to solve the error? It is always my pleasure to have your help.

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var turn = 0;

  var maru_1 = maru_1()

function maru_1(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue",
 ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 150, 150)
}

var maru_2 = maru_2()

function maru_2(){
ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue",
ctx.fillRect(170, 5, 150, 150);
}

var maru_3 = maru_3()

function maru_3(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
 ctx.fillRect(335, 5, 150, 150);
 }

 var maru_4 = maru_4()

function maru_4(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
 ctx.fillRect(5, 170, 150, 150);
}

 var maru_5 = maru_5()

   function maru_5(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(170, 170, 150, 150);
   }

  var maru_6 = maru_6()

 function maru_6(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(335, 170, 150, 150);
 }

 var maru_7 = maru_7()

function maru_7(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(5, 335, 150, 150);
}

 var maru_8 = maru_8()

function maru_8(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
 ctx.fillRect(170, 335, 150, 150);
}

 var maru_9 = maru_9()

function maru_9(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(335, 335, 150, 150);
  }

var img = new Image();
img.src = "maru.png";

var img_2 = new Image();
img_2.src = "batsu.png";


 var player = canvas.addEventListener('click', function player(){

  var x = event.screenX;
  var y = event.screenY; 

  var imgTemp;

if(turn%2==0){
 imgTemp = img
} else {
 imgTemp = img_2
}

  if(x<150 && y<190){
    ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 5, 145, 140)
     turn+=1;    
      return true;
  }else if(x>160 && x<335 && y<190){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 168, 5, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x>335 && x<470 && y<190){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 330, 5, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x<160 && y>=175 && y<340){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 170, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x>170 && x<335 && y>175 && y<340){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 170, 170, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x>335 &&  x<470 && y>195 && y<340){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 335, 170, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x<160 && y>340 && y<550){ 
       ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 335, 145, 140)
       turn+=1;
       return true;
  }else if(x>165 && x<335 && y>340 && y<550){
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 170, 335, 145, 140)
        turn+=1;
        return true;
    }else if(x>335 && x<470 &&  y>340 && y<550){
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 335, 335, 145, 140) 
        turn+=1;
        return true;
        }{
        return false;  
     }

    }, false);
if (player=true){
   canvas.removeEventListener("click",player);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Your code is not readable

Priblem 2: You are re-assigning `boolean: true` to `player` inside your **if** block which is causing the issue with `removeEventListener`.

If you want to add click listener only once then you can remove the listener inside your player function. I modified your code, take a look:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var turn = 0;

var img = new Image();
img.src = "maru.png";

var img_2 = new Image();
img_2.src = "batsu.png";

function fillRect(ctx, x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue",
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h)
}

function player(event) {
    if (player) {
        canvas.removeEventListener("click", player);
    }

    var x = event.screenX;
    var y = event.screenY;

    var imgTemp;

    if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        imgTemp = img
    } else {
        imgTemp = img_2
    }

    if (x < 150 && y < 190) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 5, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x > 160 && x < 335 && y < 190) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 168, 5, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x > 335 && x < 470 && y < 190) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 330, 5, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x < 160 && y >= 175 && y < 340) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 170, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x > 170 && x < 335 && y > 175 && y < 340) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 170, 170, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x > 335 && x < 470 && y > 195 && y < 340) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 335, 170, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x < 160 && y > 340 && y < 550) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 335, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x > 165 && x < 335 && y > 340 && y < 550) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 170, 335, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    } else if (x > 335 && x < 470 && y > 340 && y < 550) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 335, 335, 145, 140)
        turn += 1;
    }
}

fillRect(ctx, 5, 5, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 170, 5, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 335, 5, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 5, 170, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 170, 170, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 335, 170, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 5, 335, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 170, 335, 150, 150);
fillRect(ctx, 335, 335, 150, 150);

canvas.addEventListener('click', player);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the callback you're passing var player and not the player function,you can Change the name of the variable

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var turn = 0;

  var maru_1 = maru_1()

function maru_1(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue",
 ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 150, 150)
}

var maru_2 = maru_2()

function maru_2(){
ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue",
ctx.fillRect(170, 5, 150, 150);
}

var maru_3 = maru_3()

function maru_3(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
 ctx.fillRect(335, 5, 150, 150);
 }

 var maru_4 = maru_4()

function maru_4(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
 ctx.fillRect(5, 170, 150, 150);
}

 var maru_5 = maru_5()

   function maru_5(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(170, 170, 150, 150);
   }

  var maru_6 = maru_6()

 function maru_6(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(335, 170, 150, 150);
 }

 var maru_7 = maru_7()

function maru_7(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(5, 335, 150, 150);
}

 var maru_8 = maru_8()

function maru_8(){
 ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
 ctx.fillRect(170, 335, 150, 150);
}

 var maru_9 = maru_9()

function maru_9(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(335, 335, 150, 150);
  }

var img = new Image();
img.src = "maru.png";

var img_2 = new Image();
img_2.src = "batsu.png";

function player(){

  var x = event.screenX;
  var y = event.screenY; 

  var imgTemp;

if(turn%2==0){
 imgTemp = img
} else {
 imgTemp = img_2
}

  if(x<150 && y<190){
    ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 5, 145, 140)
     turn+=1;    
      return true;
  }else if(x>160 && x<335 && y<190){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 168, 5, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x>335 && x<470 && y<190){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 330, 5, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x<160 && y>=175 && y<340){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 170, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x>170 && x<335 && y>175 && y<340){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 170, 170, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x>335 &&  x<470 && y>195 && y<340){
      ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 335, 170, 145, 140)
      turn+=1;
      return true;
  }else if(x<160 && y>340 && y<550){ 
       ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 5, 335, 145, 140)
       turn+=1;
       return true;
  }else if(x>165 && x<335 && y>340 && y<550){
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 170, 335, 145, 140)
        turn+=1;
        return true;
    }else if(x>335 && x<470 &&  y>340 && y<550){
        ctx.drawImage(imgTemp, 335, 335, 145, 140) 
        turn+=1;
        return true;
        }{
        return false;  
     }

    }
 var player2 = canvas.addEventListener('click', player,false)
if (true){ // put your condition here
   canvas.removeEventListener("click",player);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The return value of `addEventListener` function is `undefined`. So `player2` in your example will always be `undefined`   [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: You are right @Prakhar. My point is to pass the function as callback and not the variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Could I ask if I want to prevent the duplicate of the pictures by double click of the same square  , how can I do the action by removeEventlistener and the if statement? Than You very much again and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: you can set some variable with on click listener on the square and check the condition if that variable is set then remove the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

`removeEventListener()` function expects three parameters. First is the `type` of event, second is the `EventListener` function which was originally registered and third is optional `options` object.

```
target.removeEventListener(type, listenerFunction, options)
```

What you are passing as the second parameter in your example is not the original callback function.
In order to remove an event listener, you must use a named function as the callback.

So define your `player` function beforehand

`function player(){ .... }`

And use it to register the event listener

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', player )
```

And then to remove this

```
canvas.removeEventListener("click",player)
```